# Configuração de .htaccess para aplicação NodeJS e React utilizando o mesmo domínio

Tags: node.js, react, apache, deploy, cpanel

Olá,

Estou configurando uma aplicação em um servidor cPanel.
O backend foi desenvolvido em Node JS e será publicado em uma URL com o seguinte formato: https://teste.com/api;

O frontend foi desenvolvido em React JS e será publicado na URL https://teste.com

O arquivo .htaccess foi configurado dessa forma, conforme documentação ([Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing))

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

A dúvida é como posso configurar o arquivo .htaccess para redirecionar para index.html (como já faz), menos para quando a URL solicitada for **https://teste.com/api/qualquercoisa ?**

Obrigado,

Comment: Não sabia que se usava .htacces com nodejs. Para mim .htacces só se usava com apache.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, é apache sim! Estou publicando uma aplicação Node no servidor apache.

Comment: Você está usando o /api com um apache-proxy?!